# In node How to get the result of other module method

Tags: node.js

In my node application i need to get the result of other module  method.How can i do that.

app.js

```
 var mod=require('/otherModule');
 var value=mod.callingOtherModuleMethod();
 someOtherFn(value);
```

In above module if callingOtherModuleMethod() takes more time to return the result means.still node wait for that result or it will call the someOtherFn(value); method

otherModule.js

```
 exports.callingOtherModuleMethod=function(){

     var data='myData'; 
     return data;

 }
```

Comment: I didnt understand the question. Could you please explain more?

Comment: @thefourtheye i have just edited the question to make it clear..

Comment: As far as I know, node programs can execute in asynchronous fashion but not by default. So, there is no way that function can be called, unless you explicitly do so.

Comment: @thefourtheye ok if callingOtherModuleMethod() takes more time to return the result means.still node wait for that result or it will call the  someOtherFn(value); method.

Comment: It will wait for sure.